# Resizing the image after taking the path of the image with HTML and css

Tags: javascript, html, css, image-resizing

I'm writing an admin page for an animal center (university project). The features of this page are that you can add/remove/update information about the animal in the shelter. One of the features is that when the admin user has placed an image of an animal, he has the ability to preview the image by entering the name of the image plus the extension. Here is where my problem occurs. Every time the preview button is clicked the image is shown but the original size of the image which bigger than the div width and height stays the same even after many tries of resizing it with CSS.
Here is my HTML and CSS code in case you need it:

```
<?php require_once 'controller/authcontroller.php';

    if (isset($_POST['image-preview'])) {
        $Image = $_POST['animalPath'];
        $animalName = $_POST['animalName'];
        $animalId = $_POST['animalId'];
        $animalType = $_POST['animalType'];
        $animalPath = $_POST['animalPath'];
        $animalDescription = $_POST['animalDescription'];
        if (isset($_POST['animalMI'])) {
            $animalMI = "checked";
        }
        else {
            $animalMI = "";
        }
    }

    if (isset($_POST['Reset'])) {
        $animalId = "";
        $animalName = "";
        $animalPath = "";
        $animalType = "";
        $animalDescription = "";
    }

?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <title>try</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="content-background">
        <div class="content">   
            <form action="index.php" method="post">
                <div class="search">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th id="t1"><label for="animalId" class="label" id="id-lbl">Search for Id</label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td id="t2"><input type="text" name="animalId" value="<?php echo $animalId; ?>" class="input-box" id="input1"></td>
                            <td id="t3"><button type="submit" name="search-btn" id="search-button">Search</button></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="alert">
                    <?php //if(isset($ERRORS['animal-id'])): ?>
                        <img src="Images/Error.webp" alt="error img" class="error">
                        <p><?php //echo $ERRORS['animal-id']; ?>H</p>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="animal_name">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="animalName" class="label" id="name-lbl">Animal name</label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="animalName" value="<?php echo $animalName; ?>" class="input-box"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="alert">
                    <?php if(isset($ERRORS['animal-name'])): ?>
                        <img src="Images/Error.webp" alt="error img" class="error">
                        <p><?php echo $ERRORS['animal-name']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="animal_type">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="animaltype" class="label" id="type-lbl">Animal type (choose between cat, dog and other):</label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><input type="text" name="animalType" value="<?php echo $animalType; ?>" class="input-box"></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>                    
                </div>
                <div class="alert">
                    <?php if(isset($ERRORS['animal-type'])): ?>
                        <img src="Images/Error.webp" alt="error img" class="error">
                        <p><?php echo $ERRORS['animal-type']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="animal_MI">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th>
                                <label for="animalMI" class="label"  id="MI-lbl">If the animal have a medical issue please check this</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" name="animalMI" id="MI" <?php echo $animalMI; ?>>
                            </th>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    
                </div>
                <div class="animal_image">
                    <table id="table-path">
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="animalPath" class="label" id="path-lbl">Image's path for the animal:</label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                <input type="text" name="animalPath" value="<?php echo $animalPath; ?>" class="input-box" id="Path">
                                <button type="submit" name="image-preview" class="button">Preview</button>
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                    <?php if(isset($_POST['image-preview'])): ?>
                        <div class="postimg">
                            <?php $Image = $_POST['animalPath']; ?>
                            <?php if(!empty($Image)): ?>
                                <img src="Images/<?php echo $Image; ?>" alt="Image" id="animal-image">
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="alert">
                    <?php if(isset($ERRORS['animal-path'])): ?>
                        <img src="Images/Error.webp" alt="error img" class="error">
                        <p><?php echo $ERRORS['animal-path']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="animal_description">
                    <table>
                        <tr>
                            <th><label for="animalDescription" class="label" id="descrip-lbl">Animal's description:</label></th>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td><textarea name="animalDescription" id="animal-Description" cols="30" rows="10"><?php echo $animalDescription; ?></textarea></td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div class="alert">
                    <?php if(isset($ERRORS['animal-description'])): ?>
                        <img src="Images/Error.webp" alt="error img" class="error">
                        <p><?php echo $ERRORS['animal-description']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
                <div class="button">
                    <button type="submit" name="Update" class="button">Update</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="Add" class="button">Add</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="Delete" class="button">Delete</button>
                    <button type="submit" name="Reset" class="button">Reset</button>
                </div>
                <div class="fin-mess">
                    <?php if(isset($ERRORS['final-message'])): ?>
                        <p id="final-mess"><?php echo $ERRORS['final-message']; ?></p>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@100&display=swap');
*{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.content{
    margin: 125px 16% 65px 16%;
}
#id-lbl{
    margin-left: 0%;
}
.search{
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
.alert img{
    position: relative;
    width: 15px;
}
.alert p{
    position: relative;
    top: -19px;
    left: 20px;
    display: block;
    color: #555;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: small;
}
button{
    border: 1.5px solid #1f52f9;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    outline: none;
    background: #4971f6;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 5px 30px;
    font-size: 15px;
}
.input-box{
    border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    height: 35px;
    width: 80%;
    padding: 0 10px;
    font-size: 15px;
    outline: none;
}
#MI{
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid #d5d2d2;
    border-radius: 5px;
    width: 35px;
    top: 2px;
    padding: 0 10px;
    outline: none;
}
label{
    position: relative;
    font-family: 'Roboto';
    font-size: 20px;
    color:#555;
    pointer-events: none;
    transition: 0.2s all;
}
table{
    width: 90%;
    border-spacing: 15px;
}
#input1{
    width: 100%;
}
#search-button{
    margin-left: 5%;
}
#name-lbl{
    margin-left: -15%;
}
#animal-Description{
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 15px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
}
#Path{
    width: 50%;
}
#table-ppath td{
    width: 50%;
}
.postimg{
    width: 600px;
}
#animal-image{
    width: 600px;
    display: block;
}
```

Also here is what's happening when I want to preview an image with that feature:[In this image, you can see just one-quarter of the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VCdC0.jpg)

Comment: set `max-width:100%`

Comment: For the div of the image or the image itself?